# How can I get started with a Home Brew QRP?

Tags: transceiver

I want to build a simple 40 meter CW transmitter and Receiver pair. What should I do to get started into home-brew HF RF devices?

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on how to find a ready-made kit, or are you looking for suggestions on how to get started making your own from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a [BitX 20a](http://qrpkits.com/bitx20a.html), which was fairly complex, but a really neat kit. If your soldering skills are ok, and you can wind small wire through tiny donut shaped cores, you will have a lot of fun.

[The SMK-2 40m kit](http://qrpkits.com/smk2.html) might meet your needs (40 meter CW), but it's surface mount. Don't be afraid of that, with a good magnifying glass, and some inexpensive chinese made soldering tools and some solder paste, it's easy.

I also built a [Sudden Storm](http://jaunty-electronics.com/blog/2012/08/sudden-storm-hf-receiver-in-a-tuna-can/) from [KF5OBS](http://qrpkits.com/). They have several simpler, small kits that might be a good fit.

I've found kits a great way to learn. I learned a lot trying to get my BitX to work, I found a few errors I made, but I learned a lot about the theory in the process. Don't be afraid to learn as you go!